# NodeJS Memory Leaks: What classifies as a reference in a closure

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, closures

I understand that objects can avoid garbage collection in some scenarios, if there exists references within closures.

Does a reference mean that a reference of the object needs to be assigned to something? Or would calling / getting a property of the object also count as a reference?

For example, would the following inner functions create references to the object in the closures?

```
const someObject = {
  myProp: 123, 
  callable: () => console.log('hello!')
}

function outer() {
  const innerAssign = () => {
     const innerVar = someObject.myProp;  // does this create reference in closure?
  }

  const innerCall = () => {
     someObject.callable();  // does this create reference in closure?
  }

  const innerRef = () => {
    const newRef = someObject;  // this surely creates a reference in closure
  }
}
```

Also, does creating / using an array of keys of object properties create a reference to the original object?

For example

```
const keys = Object.keys(someObject);
```

Another question: When another reference is created to an existing object in a new scope, additional memory is allocated on the heap for that object - is this correct?

Comment: Object keys by themselves are just independent strings or symbols.  They don't have any reference to the object they came from.

Comment: Other parts of your question are referring to object properties use in methods of the object.  Properties are never garbage collected independently of the object they are on.  So, all that matters here is who has a reference to the object itself.  Since a method can't be called without someone having a reference to the object, that generally takes care of things for you.  If nobody has a reference to the object, then nobody can ever call any of its methods and thus the object is available for GC.  If someone has a reference to the object, then it won't be GCed.

Comment: So (1) if a property of an object is assigned to a variable in a closure, it does not create a reference to the object, and (2) if a method of the object is called within the closure, it does create a reference to the object. This is correct?

Comment: Well, it depends.  Your code is a bit of a contrived example because, though you define three inner functions, there is no code that ever actually calls them so it's possible for the engine to be smart enough to ignore them entirely since the optimizer could completely remove them.  If they were callable, then nothing can be GCed for as long as they are callable because all of the inner functions contain references to `someObject`.  So, as long as any of the inner functions can be called and are reachable, `someObject` cannot be GCed.

Comment: The three different inner functions are all referencing `someObject` so it doesn't matter that they do different things with it.  They are each a reference if they can be called.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, does creating / using an array of keys of object properties create a reference to the original object?

No, it does not.  Object keys by themselves are just independent strings or symbols. They don't have any reference to the object they came from.

Other parts of your question are referring to object properties used in methods of the object. Properties are never garbage collected independently of the object they are on. So, all that matters here is who has a reference to the object itself. Since a method can't be called without someone having a reference to the object, that generally takes care of things for you. If nobody has a reference to the object, then nobody can ever call any of its methods and thus the object is available for GC. If someone has a reference to the object, then it won't be GCed.

> So (1) if a property of an object is assigned to a variable in a closure, it does not create a reference to the object, and (2) if a method of the object is called within the closure, it does create a reference to the object. This is correct?

Well, it depends. Your code is a bit of a contrived example because, though you define three inner functions, there is no code that ever actually calls them so it's possible for the engine to be smart enough to ignore them entirely since the optimizer could completely remove them. If they were callable, then nothing can be GCed for as long as they are callable because all of the inner functions contain references to `someObject`. So, as long as any of the inner functions can be called and are reachable, `someObject` cannot be GCed.

The three different inner functions are all referencing `someObject` so it doesn't matter that they do different things with it. They are each a reference if they can be called.

> Another question: When another reference is created to an existing object in a new scope, additional memory is allocated on the heap for that object - is this correct?

It's not entirely clear what you mean by this since you don't show a specific code example.  If you create a variable in a new scope that is assigned `someObject`, then the only new memory that is allocated is for the variable itself.  That variable contains a pointer to the one copy of `someObject`.  There is not a separate copy of `someObject` just because there's another reference to it in some other scope.